# Incorrect logic comparing strings?

Tags: java, regex, for-loop, boolean, logic

This program is supposed to compare "DNA" strings.

Input:
3
ATGC
TACG
ATGC
CGTA
AGQ
TCF

First line represents how many times the program will be run. Each time it runs, it compares the two strings. A matches with T and vice versa. G matches with C and vise versa. So if the first letter of string 1 is A, the first letter of string 2 should be T. If the next one is T, the next one on the other string should be A and etc. If a letter other than A, T, G, or C appear, it is a bad sample. If its bad, print out bad, if its good, print out good. I tried many different combinations to this and they all worked fine but according the the judge's test data (they have different input), it failed. Does anyone see anything wrong with this? I know it might not be the most efficient way of getting the job done but it did, at least to my understanding.

Output:
GOOD
BAD
BAD

```
public class DNA
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (new File ("dna.dat"));
        int T = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
        boolean valid = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < T; i++)
        {
            String strand1 = scan.nextLine();
            strand1 = strand1.toUpperCase();
            String strand2 = scan.nextLine();
            strand2 = strand2.toUpperCase();
            for (int p = 0; p < strand1.length(); p++)
            {
                if (strand1.charAt(p) != 'A' && strand1.charAt(p) != 'T' && strand1.charAt(p) != 'G' && strand1.charAt(p) != 'C'
                    && strand2.charAt(p) != 'A' && strand2.charAt(p) != 'T' && strand2.charAt(p) != 'G' && strand2.charAt(p) != 'C')
                {
                    valid = false;
                    break;
                }
                if (strand1.length() != strand2.length())
                {
                    valid = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (valid)
            {
                for (int p = 0; p < strand1.length(); p++)
                {
                    if ((strand1.charAt(p) == 'A' && strand2.charAt(p) == 'T') || (strand1.charAt(p) == 'T' && strand2.charAt(p) == 'A')
                         || (strand1.charAt(p) == 'G' && strand2.charAt(p) == 'C') || (strand1.charAt(p) == 'C' && strand2.charAt(p) == 'G'))
                        valid = true;
                    else
                        valid = false;
                }
            }
            if (valid)
                out.println("GOOD");
            else
                out.println("BAD");
            valid = true;
        }

    }
}
```

I added the toUpperCase and compared the strings for equal length just as a last attempt to see if their data maybe had some lowercase letters or different length strings though they SHOULD all be the same length and uppercase. Nevertheless, the program was still rejected for "failing the judges test data."

Answer (score 1):

You need a break in the second for loop when `valid = false`.  For example if characters 1,2,3 are wrong but #4 is a match you will still end up with valid.

I would convert the strings to arrays to make things easier:

```
for (int i = 0; i < T; i++)
{
    boolean valid = true;
    String strand1 = scan.nextLine();
    strand1 = strand1.toUpperCase();
    String strand2 = scan.nextLine();
    strand2 = strand2.toUpperCase();
    if ( strand1.length() != strand2.length())
    {
        valid = false;
    }
    if (valid) {
        char[] c1 = strand1.toCharArray();
        char[] c2 = strand2.toCharArray();

        for (int p = 0; p < c1.length; p++)
        {
            if (-1 == "ACTG".indexOf(c1[p]) || -1 == "ACTG".indexOf(c2[p]))
            {
                valid = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (valid)
        {
            for (int p = 0; p < c1.length; p++)
            {
                if (('A' == c1[p] && 'T' != c2[p]) ||
                    ('T' == c1[p] && 'A' != c2[p]) ||
                    ('C' == c1[p] && 'G' != c2[p]) ||
                    ('G' == c1[p] && 'C' != c2[p])) {
                    valid = false;
                    break;
                 }
            }
        }
    }
    if (valid)
        System.out.println("GOOD");
    else
        System.out.println("BAD");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change all

```
&&
```

in

```
if (strand1.charAt(p) != 'A' && strand1.charAt(p) != 'T' && strand1.charAt(p) != 'G' && strand1.charAt(p) != 'C' && strand2.charAt(p) != 'A' && strand2.charAt(p) != 'T' && strand2.charAt(p) != 'G' && strand2.charAt(p) != 'C')
```

to

```
||
```

if ANY, not ALL character is other than A, T, G, or C, then we exit the loop.

Comment: If I change it to ||, wouldn't that make it false even when its true? For example if we had ACG, it wouldn't meet the first condition strand1.charAt(p) != 'A' thus, making it false. If its &&, it checks that ALL characters are either A, C, G, or T. If they aren't ALL either A, C, G, or T, the boolean value is set to false, if they are however, it stays true and continues on with the rest of the program.